How to manually set all learnable parameters in PyTorch model to a fixed value
For some testing purposes, I would like to manually set all the learnable parameters of a PyTorch torch.nn.Module model to a fixed value (I'm comparing two models that should be the same, but they seem to train considerably differently, so I want to sanity check the forward method). Is there a simple way to do this?

One way that I have worked out is the following, assuming a model called model:
# fill model parameters with all ones
fill_value = 1.0

# loop over all parameters
for p in model.parameters():
    if p.requires_grad:  # only change learnable parameters
        with torch.no_grad():
            p.fill_(fill_value)  # in-place fill
            # p.zero_()  # this can be used if setting every parameter to zero

There may be a better way.
Update
I also found I needed to reset buffers (e.g., for BatchNorm2d modules within the models), so I have done:
def fill_buffers(model, value=0.0):
    for b in model.buffers():
        b.fill_(value)

# fill buffers with zeros
fill_buffers(model, 0.0)

